# NGINX Rules redirect with query string not working

Tags: ajax, redirect, nginx

We are trying to redirect all the files that have this format:

```
ajax/(.*).php
```

towards

```
ajax/getfile.php?file=$1
```

We always get 404 not when testing `ajax/somefile.php` found but we discoverd that by adding a trailing slash the rule works:

```
ajax/somefile.php/
```

The rule we have so far is:

```
  location /ajax {
        rewrite ^/ajax/(.*).php/?$ /ajax/getfile.php?file=$1;
    }
```

The weirdest thing is that we have a similar scenario that actually works!

```
  location /javasc{
        rewrite ^/javasc/(.*).js/?$ /javasc/view.php?file=$1;
    }
```

Comment: I'm 99% sure you have directive like `location ~ \.php$ {...}`

Comment: Yes @AlexeyTen , we do have it because we need to tell nginx php-fpm cgi ip but how to resolve it ?

Comment: Hi @AlexeyTen, apparently we need the  directive location ~ \.php$ {...}, any idea on how to solve the issue? Thanks